# join two table to replace new value from 2th table if exist

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have two table like belew

```
Table1: 
CId -- Name -- Price -- MId
1       A      100   -- 1
2       B      110   -- 1
3       C      120   -- 1
4       D      120   -- 2

Table2:
Id -- UserId -- CId -- Price
1     1         2      200
1     2         2      200
```

I want to get data from Table one But if there is a record in Table2 that refrenced to Table1 CId then Price of Table2 replace with Price of Table1.

For example my UserId is 1 AND MId is 1 if I get data by mentioned senario I should get in result;

```
1       A      100  
2       B      200
3       C      120
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get by `left join` where you check `null` value in second table. if second price is `null` then use `first table's price`.

```
SELECT t1.CId, t1.name 
CASE WHEN t2.price IS NULL 
THEN t1.price 
ELSE t2.price END AS Price 
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
ON t1.CId = t2.CId 
WHERE WHERE t1.MId = 1 
AND (t2.UserId = 1 OR t2.UserId IS NULL);
```

Try This Hopeful this will work.

Comment: @ali you want get only replace record column ? or other column like 'CId, name'

Comment: or you want which record is replace you want get only those record ?

Comment: @Ali according to your question my answer is correct

Comment: yes, like your answer @SimarjeetSingh Panghlia answered. But a litlle problem exist is when I add WHERE t2.UserId=? AND t1.CourseId=?, I will just return replcaed record, When I remove this works correctly

Comment: @Ali  You are right because userId exist on second table so if t2.UserId exist in second table then its return replaced record always.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101966/discussion-between-vipin-jain-and-ali).

Answer (score 2):

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b26d2/1)

try this

```
select t1.cid,t1.name,
case when t2.cid is null
then t1.price 
else t2.price 
end as Price
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.cid =t2.cid
where t1.mid =1 AND (t2.UserId = 1 OR t2.UserId IS NULL);
```

Comment: I will try, and give feedback

Comment: I return just the replaced record, other record from table1 not return

Comment: When I add this it return just matched records and other don't return.  WHERE t2.UserId=? AND t1.CourseId=?, When I remove it it will work.

Comment: Sorry, Your asnwer was right the question, But I edited the question, Please take look at it and modify your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
    [cid] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [price] [bigint] NULL,
    [MID] [int] NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [table2](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [userid] [int] NULL,
    [CId] [int] NULL,
    [price] [bigint] NULL
)

GO
INSERT [dbo].[table1] ([cid], [Name], [price], [MID]) VALUES (1, N'A', 100, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[table1] ([cid], [Name], [price], [MID]) VALUES (2, N'B', 110, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[table1] ([cid], [Name], [price], [MID]) VALUES (3, N'C', 120, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[table1] ([cid], [Name], [price], [MID]) VALUES (4, N'D', 120, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[table2] ([id], [userid], [CId], [price]) VALUES (1, 1, 2, 200)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[table2] ([id], [userid], [CId], [price]) VALUES (1, 2, 2, 200)
GO


and  Query-----------------------------------

SELECT        t1.cid, t1.Name,
              case when t1.cid=t2.cid then t2.price else t1.price end as Price
FROM          table1  t1
INNER JOIN  table2 t2 ON t1.MID = t2.userid
where t2.userid=1
```